# Properties of recursive languages

Tags: recursion, properties, enumerable

Can anybody please help me with these questions?

Which properties of the following recursive languages are recursively enumerable?

**L_1 = { L | L is regular}**

**L_2 = { L | L contains < A > for some A,which holds on sequence  000111000}**

**L_3 = { L |  L contains < A > for some A, which holds on epsilon }**

Answer (score 0):

Recursive languages (also known as Decidable languages) are the languages for which there exists a turing machine which accepts the language and halts on both both accepting and non-accepting words.

Recursive enumerable languages are languages for which there exists a turing machine which halts on accepting strings.

So set of Recursive languages is a subset of set of Recursively enumerable languages.

So, if I understood the question right, then L_1, L_2 and L_3 are recursively enumerable.